# Why does my signup form in rails no longer work when this small snippet of code is added to it?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Originally, for a signup form on my site, I had this code for the beginning of the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user)  do |f| %>
```

When I add this html id in the following code for the beginning of my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :id => 'payment-form' })  do |f| %>
```

The form no longer works.

Is there a way to still add the html id I specified above to my form while allowing my form to work? How can I go about doing that? Why doesn't the form actually process when I hit 'submit' after I add the html id.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show the HTML generated, and also what errors you're getting if any? Also did you try `<%= form_for(@user, :id => 'payment-form' )  do |f| %>`?

Comment: What doesn't work with the form? Does it not render, or do you not get your @user data when you submit? That's because you'd need to access it with `params["payment-form"]` instead of `params[:user]`

Comment: @varatis Your suggestion worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1483441 I'll add it as an answer then. Please accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<%= form_for(@user, :id => 'payment-form' ) do |f| %>`